# Parse and return string from JSON - Python

Tags: python, json

Apologies if this comes on as a noob question as I totally am or a duplicate.

I have a file on a webserver that I need to parse.
the location of the file is `/var/www/html` called `test.json`.

I want to parse it with a python script and return a `version`

```
{
"commit_id": "d44f19c",
"environment": "test",
"package_build_date": "15/05/2015",
"project": "devopstest",
"tags_at_commit": [
"v1.6.0-rc.1"
],
"version": "v1.6.0-rc.1"
}
```

Any help/guidance appreciated

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: @Selcuk I'm more concerned about how I access the file. The script is in a different folder

Comment: Why are you concerned? Have you tried parsing it and failed?

Comment: @Selcuk I can parse the file. But it's failing when importing it

Comment: Importing _where_? I suggest that you edit your question and be more clear about your specific problem(s) then. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just use *import json*:

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
```